# Sticky footer with nested div pushing the content down

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a sticky footer working, but my problem is I need the nested div #container to extend all the way to the footer.  I've tried various ways but can't make any headway.

The footer should stick to the bottom when content is short.

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">click here to reset</div>
        <div id="banner-region">click here to add content</div>
        <div id="navigation"></div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="container">
                <p>This div should extend all the way down to the bottom and touch the footer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div> 
</body>
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vu2uP/3/

Comment: Might be a case for `flexbox`.

Comment: What do you mean by "sticky footer"? Do you want the footer to always be visible and have the content scroll behind it?

Comment: @jonsuh No, sorry.  I mean that the footer will always be at the bottom of the page, even with short content

Comment: for your background, you could use somehow the faux columns technique with linear-gradient or box-shadow in body background : http://jsfiddle.net/Vu2uP/4 or http://jsfiddle.net/Vu2uP/6 with background image too

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at this if you want the container to always go down to the fixed footer: 
http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/sticky-footer-wide-header-footer2.htm